# Android - Método com retorno usando thread

Tags: java, android, thread, volley

Olá galera estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação android que usa a biblioteca volley (google) para realizar as minhas requisições http. Tenho um método que retorna um Boolean e depende do retorno da requisição, ai que esta a maldade, o método retorna o valor antes de terminar a requisição.

```
public class MyService implements IMyService {
    private Context context = null;
    private Boolean result = false;

    public MyService(Context context){
        this.context = context;  Thread
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean isUrlValida(final String url){
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String s) {
                        result = true;
                        Log.w("isUrlValida", "onResponse");
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.w("isUrlValida", "onErrorResponse");
                    }
                }
        );

        ((AppApplication) context).getRequestQueue().add(stringRequest);
        ((AppApplication) context).getRequestQueue().start();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Vou precisar realizar algum controle de Thread's ? Valeu !

Comment: qual o retorno que há?

Comment: 200 - ok, ele entra no onResponse() o problema que já retorna false sem esperar a requisição

Comment: Creio que a maneira para se trabalhar com Volley é quase a mesma quando se trabalha com AsyncTasks, você terá que implementar um "aguarde" para o usuário até obter o conteudo que você precisa.

Comment: Acrescente isto: if (s == null) { }- PARA TESTAR.

Comment: @wryel vou dar uma olhada no AsyncTasks.

Comment: @Rafael continua a mesma coisa, obrigado a todos.

Comment: Debuga cada linha para identificar onde ele entra ou não.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se pretender aguardar por uma thread poderá utilizar o método join() da class Thread, que aguarda que uma dada thread termine de executar. (Mas atenção para não bloquear a interação com o utilizador)
Exemplo:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
    });
    t.start();

    try {
        t.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}

    System.out.println("Acabou.");
```

Tem sempre a alternativa de usar o AsyncTask em que consegue estipular o retorno Boolean no fim da thread terminar, bastando definir os tipos das variáveis com que o AsyncTask lida e fazer override ao método onPostExecute(..)